# direct2d image viewer How to convert screen coordinates to image coordinates?

Tags: matrix, transform, direct2d

I'm trying to figure out how to convert the mouse position (screen coordinates) to the corresponding point on the underlying transformed image drawn on a direct2d surface.
the code here should be considered pseudo code as i'm using a modified c++/CLI wrapper around direct2d for c#, you won't be able to compile this in anything but my own project.

```
Render()
{
    //The transform matrix combines a rotation, followed by a scaling then a translation
    renderTarget.Transform = _rotate * _scale * _translate;
    RectF imageBounds = new RectF(0, 0, _imageSize.Width, _imageSize.Height);
    renderTarget.DrawBitmap(this._image, imageBounds, 1, BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear);
}
Zoom(float zoomfactor, PointF mousepos)
{
    //mousePos is in screen coordinates. I need to convert it to image coordinates.
    Matrix3x2 t = _translate.Invert();
    Matrix3x2 s = _scale.Invert();
    Matrix3x2 r = _rotate.Invert();
    PointF center = (t * s * r).TransformPoint(mousePos); 
    _scale = Matrix3x2.Scale(zoomfactor, zoomfactor, center);    
}
```

This is incorrect, the scale center starts moving around wildly when the zoomfactor increases or decreases smoothly, the resulting zoom function is not smooth and flickers a lot even though the mouse pointer is immobile on the center of the client surface. I tried all the combinations I could think of but could not figure it out.

If I set the scale center point as (imagewidth/2, imageheight/2), the resulting zoom is smooth but is always centered on the image center, so I'm pretty sure the flicker isn't due to some other buggy part of the program.

Thanks.

Comment: Try replacing `t * s * r` with `r * s * t`. And make sure the screen point is in client coordinates and *(possibly custom)* DPI is taken into consideration.

Comment: I did try it already and the flicker is worse, also the mousepos thing is merely to illustrate my goal better; I set it fixed on the client center for testing purposes as long as I don't have a reliable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it right

this gives me perfectly smooth (incremental?, relative?) zooming centered on the client center
(I abandoned the mouse position idea since I wanted to use mouse movement input to drive the zoom)

```
     protected float zoomf
    {
        get
        {
            //extract scale factor from scale matrix
            return (float)Math.Sqrt((double)((_scale.M11 * _scale.M11) 
                                              + (_scale.M21 * _scale.M21)));
        }
    }

    public void Zoom(float factor)
    {

        factor = Math.Min(zoomf, 1) * 0.006f * factor;
        factor += 1;

        Matrix3x2 t = _translation;
        t.Invert();
        PointF center = t.TransformPoint(_clientCenter);


        Matrix3x2 m = Matrix3x2.Scale(new SizeF(factor, factor), center);
        _scale = _scale * m;
        Invalidate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:** Put android:scaleType="matrix" in ImageView XML file 
**Step 2:** Convert screen touch points to Matrix value.
**Step 3:** Divide each matrix  value with Screen density parameter to
    get same coordinate value in all screens.

```
**XML**
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/myImage"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:scaleType="matrix"
  android:src="@drawable/ga"/>

**JAVA**
 @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float[] point = new float[]{event.getX(), event.getY()};
    Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
    getImageMatrix().invert(inverse);
    inverse.mapPoints(point);
    float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int[] imagePointArray = new int[2];
    imagePointArray[0] = (int) (point[0] / density);
    imagePointArray[1] = (int) (point[1] / density);
    Rect rect = new Rect( imagePointArray[0] - 20, imagePointArray[1]  - 20,  imagePointArray[0] + 20, imagePointArray[1]  + 20);//20 is the offset value near to the touch point
        boolean b = rect.contains(267, 40);//267,40 are the predefine image coordiantes
        Log.e("Touch inside ", b + "");
    return true;

}
```