# Transform Mouse point from/to Matrix

Tags: c++, winapi, direct2d

I have a drawing surface normalized to [0,1] for x and y.

If the drawing is transformed by a D2D1_MATRIX_3F, how can I transform a mouse hit at a position [x1,y1] to the actual transformed one drawn in the surface?

I tried the theory to multiply the mouse coordinates by the inverted matrix but it didn't work.

```
D2D1_POINT_2F TransformPoint(
    D2D1_MATRIX_3X2_F& x,
    D2D1_POINT_2F point
)
{
    D2D1_POINT_2F result =
    {
        point.x * x._11 + point.y * x._21 + x._31,
        point.x * x._12 + point.y * x._22 + x._32
    };
    return result;
}

// pt = a point hit test by the mouse in [0,1] for both x and y.
D2D1_MATRIX_3X2_F r1 = GetMyTransform();
D2D1InvertMatrix(&r1);
pt = TransformPoint(r1,pt);
```

2. How to do the opposite, i.e. from a surface point [x2,y2] to get the actual position in the [0,1] drawing.

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317536/direct2d-image-viewer-how-to-convert-screen-coordinates-to-image-coordinates

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* is not a problem statement. Please see [ask].